# How to get mypy to recognize login_required decorator?

Tags: python, django, mypy

I have the following Django view:

```py
@login_required
def view(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    if not request.user.some_attribute:
        return redirect("somewhere")
    return render(request, "template_name")
```

and a custom `User` model that has an attribute `some_attribute`.

I use `mypy` to enforce type checking, with this `mypy.ini`:

```
[mypy]
ignore_missing_imports = True
plugins = mypy_django_plugin.main

[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = [PROJECT NAME].settings
```

However, `mypy` errors with the following:

```
Item "AnonymousUser" of "Union[User, AnonymousUser]" has no attribute "some_attribute"
```

which makes sense because an anonymous user wouldn't have that attribute, but I have a `login_required` decorator, making `AnonymousUser`s impossible (it would be a `User`).

How do I tell `mypy` to ignore this, without using `# type: ignore`?

Comment: While not a solution, please be aware that MyPy is not misunderstanding anything here. *Your code* is saying "request is a ``HttpRequest``", with everything that implies – including that the user might be anonymous.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the issue?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What else could one provide? What should be the annotation for `request`?

Answer (score 5):

You can also subclass the `HttpRequest` and explicitly set the `user` field on your subclass to have the type explicitly defined as `User` instead of the default union pair, like so:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
from my_user_app.models import MyUser

class AuthenticatedHttpRequest(HttpRequest):
    user: MyUser
```

Then, every time you want to use the `login_required` decorator, set the type hint of the `request` argument to your subclass (in this case it would be `AuthenticatedHttpRequest`) like so:

```
@login_required
def view(request: AuthenticatedHttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    if not request.user.some_attribute:
        return redirect("somewhere")
    return render(request, "template_name")
```

This method is specified as a recommended one in [`django-stubs` readme file](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs#how-can-i-create-a-httprequest-thats-guaranteed-to-have-an-authenticated-user), which apparently you're using to source the Django skeletons for `mypy`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe casting `request.user` to the required type should work:

```py
from typing import cast

@login_required
def view(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    request.user = cast(User, request.user)
    if not request.user.some_attribute:
        return redirect("somewhere")
    return render(request, "template_name")
```

Comment: Or `assert isinstance(request.user, User)`. Hmmm  ... I was hoping that there is a UserHttpRequest or similar, as MisterMiyagi seemed to point to.